# Как увеличить textarea?

Tags: html, css

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно увеличить form (textarea) при наводке на нее курсором.

У меня размер поля 680px и в этом поле по горизонтали стоят 10 форм ввода, размер каждой 60px, что очень мало, реально ли сделать так, чтобы при наводке на него форма увеличивалась? И можно было ввести значение

Answer (score 2):

```
<textarea onfocus="this.style.height = '200px';" onblur="this.style.height = '60px';"></textarea>
```

**onfocus** При фокусе текущий textarea будет высотой 200px;

**onblur** Если ставим фокус в другом textarea текущий textarea будет высотой 60px;

Answer (score 0):

еще советую подтянуть русский язык.

**cols** - Ширина поля в символах.

**rows** - Высота поля в строках.

В помощь тебе есть JS ну или JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Можно без *JS*.

Завяжись на события `:hover` или `:focus` и для них пропиши стили, к примеру:

```
textarea {
    height: 60px;
}

textarea:hover {
    height: 200px;
}
```